# Change button text when multiple checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with changing the button text when 2 or more checkboxes are checked?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test">     
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" id="test1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="test2" id="test2">
<div class="compare-button"><span class="button">Text</span></div>
```

When only 1 checkbox is checked it should say 'Text'. When 2 or 3 are checked it should say 'Checked'.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please, share your current code

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button text based on checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940433/change-button-text-based-on-checkbox-selection)

Comment: Include that in the question, please.  And you said *multiple* checkboxes.

Comment: Try what's on the duplicate. Also, please post your code on the actual post. The more code we have, the more we can help :)

Comment: The duplicate is not exactly what I'm looking for. I can't make it so that it fits my need. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you show us what javascript code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (wrongly read the question before): I'd recommend you to count the elements with the same class. Like this:

```js
function changeText() {
    const inputElems = document.getElementsByClassName("check-class");
    let count = 0;

    for (let i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {       
        if (inputElems[i].checked === true){
            count++;
        }
    }

    const text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (count > 1) {
        text.innerText  = "Checked";
    } else {
        text.innerText  = "Text";
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check-class" name="test" id="test" onchange="changeText();" />     
<input type="checkbox" class="check-class" name="test1" id="test1" onchange="changeText();" /> 
<input type="checkbox" class="check-class" name="test2" id="test2" onchange="changeText();" />

<span id="text">Text</span>
```

Comment: Great, this is it! Thanks!